# Converting all $_POST values to integers when a HTML form has been submitted?

Tags: php

I have a web form and when it gets submitted I post the data to a PHP page. Now I need PHP to convert every value from the POST to be converted to an integer.  At the moment I tried do do it as below

```
$_POST = array_map("convert",$_POST);

function convert(val){
    return (int)$val;
}
```

Is there a built-in PHP function for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought that:

```
$res = array_map('intval', $_POST);
```

is short enough.

Answer (score 3):

What about using [intval](http://www.php.net/intval), instead of your own `convert` function ?

> Returns the integer value of var ,
>   using the specified base  for the
>   conversion (the default is base 10).

(And, of course, still using `array_map`)